# Access-control-expose-headers doesn't work in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, cors

So I've been using angularjs for my current projects and using CORS to do a http request to the server. I've noticed that in order to make cross domain call work, server needs to configure it's cors settings by using

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
```

All works fine. But actually the server needs to do a multi layer validation for the authentication, so when user first login, server returns a **JSESSIONID** and client needs to store the custom headers response into a session. But it seems that I couldn't access the **JSESSIONID**. So server reconfigure the CORS settings using

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers
```

all works fine now. **BUT** not when I test it on safari, every $http request that I've made and use

```
$cookieStore.put("JSESSIONID", headers("JSESSIONID"));
```

to set a session on my client browser, it always returns with a `null`. But on other browser it works fine.

After done some research I found [this](http://enable-cors.org/client.html) site that says the **CORS** call doesn't support in Safari especially version **5.1.7**

But I can't be too sure since I don't know if I missed something so here is my $http request code

```
$http({
   'method':'GET',
   'url':'example.com/method',
   'withCredentials':true,
   'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
}).success(function(data, response, headers, status) {
      $cookieStore.put("JSESSIONID", headers("JSESSIONID"));

      console.log($cookieStore.get("JSESSIONID")); //it always returns with a null in Safari
});
```

and this is the example of server response using google chrome

```
Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Jsessionid
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 25 Jun 2015 16:39:04 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin

Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4
authTokens:e8ea4bc3-efea-4aef-a845-a7d1f0003b83
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=F1E104CA46A46E7BF7614D9191BAD4CD
Host:deal01.customers.luna.net:9091
JSESSIONID:F1E104CA46A46E7BF7614D9191BAD4CD
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that's too late, but anyway.

I recently faced the same issue and was able to find that Safari 5.1 wants headers specified under `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` lowercased.
I.e.

```
JSESSIONID: F1E104CA46A46E7BF7614D9191BAD4CD
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Jsessionid
```

doesn't work.

```
JSESSIONID: F1E104CA46A46E7BF7614D9191BAD4CD
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: JSESSIONID
```

Doesn't work either.
This does:

```
jsessionid: F1E104CA46A46E7BF7614D9191BAD4CD
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: jsessionid
```

Comment: For me this doesn't work in Safari 5.1.7 - I have following response headers (part of them):
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers:access-token, expiry, token-type, uid, client` and `expiry:1490347497`. But still `xhr.getResponseHeader("expiry")` returns `Refused to get unsafe header expiry`. Probably there is something else in your setup.